# Regex - get all digits and letters (with non roman chars)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

If i try to use `[\d\w]`, for example, i don't get any non-roman letters (hebrew or arabic letters for example).

The main goal is to capture any signs like ,.{}()*&$ etc..

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you want `\W`? It will match `.`, `{`, etc.

Comment: Please clarify: do you want "digits and letters (with non roman chars)" or "signs like ,.{}()*&$". Examples would be helpful.

Comment: Give us an example and the regex code you're using. By default regex should match all unicode word characters (which should include hebrew etc.).